# Cómo modificar y recomponer un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataset gigante y me gustaría poder leerlo, modificarlo y volver a guardarlo.
Debido a que es gigante, no puedo cargarlo todo en memoria, hacer las operaciones y volver a guardar, por lo que lo estoy intentando por trozos, pero no logro a completarlo.

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
#Voy leyendo trozos de 10 filas.
for chunk in pd.read_csv('./train_data.csv', chunksize=10):
    #Modifico los trozos eliminando y convirtiendo
    chunk['customer_ID'] = chunk['customer_ID'].apply(lambda x: int(x[-16:], 16)).astype('int64')
    chunk['S_2'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk['S_2'])
    #Intento juntar los trozos ya modificados en un nuevo DataFrame.
    df_train = pd.concat(chunk)
```

Me falla la parte de la concatenación... y  quizá no sea necesario concatenar en nuevo DataFrame para poder ir escribiéndolo quizá a un nuevo archivo CSV, pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo "al vuelo".

Mis preguntas son:
Cómo se concatena o crea un nuevo DataFrame donde voy agregando los trozos?
Cómo podría ir escribiendo directamente los trozos a un nuevo archivo para evitarme el nuevo DataFrame que podría darme problemas de memoria?

Gracias!

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

No es buena idea utilizar `pd.concat()` adentro del ciclo `for` ya que eso ocasiona `O(N^2)` operaciones. Cada vez que utilizas `pd.concat()` procesas un `dataframe` y la operación devuelve un nuevo `dataframe`, por eso es `N^2`.

Para optimizar memoria y velocidad lo mejor sería agregar todas las partes a una lista y luego utilizar `pd.DataFrame()` o `pd.concat()` una única vez para unir todas las partes.

Ejemplo genérico con el siguiente `dataframe` en un archivo "sample2.csv"

```
    col1    col2
0   1       11
1   2       12
2   3       13
3   4       14
4   5       15
5   6       16
6   7       17
7   8       18
8   9       19
9   10      20
```

Primero creamos una lista vacía, obtenemos las partes (Chunks) y hacemos el proceso que se necesite (En este ejemplo es algo muy sencillo), adjuntamos las partes a la lista y al final utilizamos una sola vez `pd.concat()`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

chunks = []

for chunk in pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', chunksize=5):
    chunk['col3'] = chunk['col1'] + chunk['col2']
    chunks.append(chunk)
    
df = pd.concat(chunks)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       11      12
1   2       12      14
2   3       13      16
3   4       14      18
4   5       15      20
5   6       16      22
6   7       17      24
7   8       18      26
8   9       19      28
9   10      20      30
```

**Edición:** Con el fin de aclarar por qué no funciona `pd.concat()` (Pero no sería eficiente como lo expliqué en la sección anterior).

Lo que hace falta es utilizar `df_train` adentro de `pd.concat()`, pero `df_train` debe ser un `dataframe` por lo que haría falta que crees uno vacío.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for chunk in pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', chunksize=5):
    chunk['col3'] = chunk['col1'] + chunk['col2']
    df = pd.concat([df, chunk])
```

**Edición 2:** Ahora, para leer el `dataframe` modificarlo y escribirlo en un nuevo archivo podrías utilizar `to_csv()`

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

header = True

for chunk in pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', chunksize=5):
    chunk['col3'] = chunk['col1'] + chunk['col2']
    chunk.to_csv('new_sample2.csv', header = header, mode='a')
    header = False
```

El argumento `header` hace que los nombres de las columnas se muestren, si deseas que cada `chunk` se escriba con los nombres de las columnas entonces déjalo en `True`, pero si deseas que únicamente se escriban una vez al inicio del archivo entonces puedes utilizarlo como lo puse en el ejemplo, en la primera iteración será `True` y en las demás será `False`.

El argumento `mode='a'` significa `append` es decir, concatena los chunks en un mismo archivo

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: Buen día @RobertoGimenez, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación. De hecho, estoy aún revisando la respuesta para verificar si es útil o no, ya que en el primer intento, tras varios días probándolo, tuve que resetear el equipo porque no respondía... Dado que el dataframe es tan grande, me lleva tiempo la verificación. Encuentro algunos problemas, ya que el nuevo archivo generado es aún más grande que el original, así como el hecho de que hacer chunks para agruparlos en un array y concatenar en una dataframe. Lo dicho, en cuanto pueda validarlo, lo acepto.

Comment: En la última parte de la respuesta puse un método para ir escribiendo un archivo al mismo tiempo que el original se procesa, yo creo que esa opción sería más conveniente

Comment: Sí, yo tb lo creo. Lo que no acabo de entender y estoy revisando es por qué el nuevo archivo generado es mayor que el original después de eliminar datos del original que supuestamente deberían hacer el archivo más pequeño. Creo que en mi revisión, hice alguna cosa mal y estoy chequeando esta parte. Cuando lo tenga, comento.

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es poner un if y un contador, por ejemplo 10 y que al llegar a 10 termine el proceso y revisar el archivo